# Using MAX function in DateADD SQL. Error - Invalid aggregate function in where clause [MAX(date)]

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dateadd, maxdate

I have a table 'CSALES' having columns such as customerid,transactiondate,quantity,price. I'm trying to find customers who have not been active in 1 month from a list of dates present in the transactiondate column. I've tried the following code but I'm unsure about the approach and the code is giving a compilation error

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID
FROM CSALES C

WHERE C.CUSTOMERID  NOT IN
(
    SELECT CS.CUSTOMERID FROM CSALES as CS
    WHERE CS.TRANSACTIONDATE > DATEADD(month, -1, MAX(CS.TRANSACTIONDATE )
);
```

I'm getting the following error

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid aggregate function in where clause [MAX(CS.TRANSACTIONDATE)]
```

What changes should I make in the code to reflect the requirement? Would MAX(date) be a right approach ?

Comment: Define precisely what "last month" means. Today is May 7 2022 - what lower and upper boundaries do you consider for "last month"?

Comment: Apologies, by last month, I meant one month. I've edited the question.

Comment: It is snowflake. I've edited the tag.

Comment: Just use today's date. Max date is irrelevant here.

Comment: Or if you want relative to all transactions in the table regardless of customer `max(dt) over ()`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID
FROM
  CSSALES
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
HAVING
  MAX(TRANSACTIONDATE) < ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE(),-1)
```

Shawnt00 is right the max date in the transaction table is irrelevant if you just want any customer that hasn't been active in 1 calendar month.

In snowflake use `CURRENT_DATE()` to get the date portion of Today then  `ADD_MONTHS(date,int)` to get months.  Other functions work two but these are pretty easy.  If you only want customers to remove duplicate CUSTOMERIDS group by the column.

Answer (score 1):

I think  I am about to just repeat Matt's code, but...

With a CTE for some test data:

```
WITH CSALES(CUSTOMERID, TRANSACTIONDATE) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, '2022-05-08'::date), -- to recent
    (1, '2021-05-08'::date),
    
    (2, '2021-05-08'::date), -- old enough
    (2, '2020-05-08'::date)
)
```

We can use [HAVING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having.html) for a post aggregation filter.

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, MAX(C.TRANSACTIONDATE) as last_trans
FROM CSALES C
GROUP BY 1
HAVING last_trans < DATEADD(month,-1,current_date());
```

As Matt noted there are few ways to find the "one month ago today" he used [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/add_months.html), I have used [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html)

| CUSTOMERID | LAST_TRANS |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-05-08 |

Now this code works the same as:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID
FROM (
    SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, MAX(C.TRANSACTIONDATE) as last_trans
    FROM CSALES C
    GROUP BY 1
)
WHERE last_trans < DATEADD(month,-1,current_date());
```

which gives:

| CUSTOMERID |
| --- |
| 2 |

Albeit we now have hidden away the last transaction, if that was what was wanted, and added some extra select layers for no high level value.

And thus if we want to hide the last_tran in the HAVING version, we can because we have already working code, we can just push the MAX into the HAVING (and we have Matt's code)

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID
FROM CSALES C
GROUP BY 1
HAVING MAX(C.TRANSACTIONDATE) < DATEADD(month,-1,current_date());
```

which gives for the demo code:

| CUSTOMERID |
| --- |
| 2 |

### Date Options:

There are a couple ways to alter date/time, depending how you like to order you logic, I tend to prefer DATEADD:

```
SELECT 
    current_date() as cd_a,
    CURRENT_DATE as cd_b,
    DATEADD(month, -1, cd_a) as one_month_ago_a,
    ADD_MONTHS(cd_a, -1) as one_month_ago_b;
```

gives:

| CD_A | CD_B | ONE_MONTH_AGO_A | ONE_MONTH_AGO_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-07 | 2022-05-07 | 2022-04-07 | 2022-04-07 |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  C.CUSTOMERID
FROM
  CSALES C
GROUP BY
  C.CUSTOMERID
HAVING
  MAX(C.TRANSACTIONDATE)
  <
  DATEADD(
    month,
    -1,
    (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONDATE) FROM CSALES)
  )
```

Or, assuming you have a customer table...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  CUSTOMER   C
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM CSALES   CS
     WHERE CS.CUSTOMERID       = C.ID
       AND CS.TRANSACTIONDATE >= DATEADD(
                                   month,
                                   -1,
                                   (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONDATE) FROM CSALES)
                                 )
  )
```

Demo : [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=564246a4a739de4864fd66afe5f8452d)

Comment: I think DATEADD(month, -1, MAX(CS.TRANSACTIONDATE ) needs to be inside the subquery MAX for this to work the way he wants.

Comment: @bruce ooops, shouldn't post from my phone

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple possibilities, you must check which is faster

> ```
> SELECT C.CUSTOMERID
> FROM CSALES C
>
> WHERE C.CUSTOMERID  NOT IN
> (
>     SELECT CS.CUSTOMERID FROM CSALES as CS CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONDATE) maxdate FROM CSALES) t1
>     WHERE CS.TRANSACTIONDATE > DATEADD(month, -1, maxdate)
> );
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | CUSTOMERID |
> | ---------: |
> |          4 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT C.CUSTOMERID
> FROM CSALES C CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONDATE) maxdate FROM CSALES) t1
> WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CSALES WHERE CUSTOMERID = c.CUSTOMERID AND TRANSACTIONDATE > DATEADD(month, -1, maxdate))
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | CUSTOMERID |
> | ---------: |
> |          4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c079d410b9906d9b6b0b1f83ec65f03)*

Comment: ok thank you i corrected my second query

Comment: That only excludes a customer if they've had no sales older than 1month.  If they've had sales older than 1month ***and*** more recently, they'll still be included (though they should not).  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9f4f9385ed9f8182ee3f26faf42a37a

Comment: Ok, yes i see so i changed it again, where it uses NOT EXISTS